# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The server version is not supported. The target server must be SQL Server 2000 or later

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I am trying to connect SQL Server 2008 Express Edition using JDBC. I have included SQLServer Driver 3.0 (sqljdbc.jar) and I am using JDK 1.5.

Below are my code snippet:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://10.54.10.190:1433;databaseName=SADB_database", "user", "password");

I am getting below exception:

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The server version is not supported. The target server must be SQL Server 2000 or later.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.DBComms.Prelogin(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.DBComms.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.loginWithoutFailover(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
```

Please help any one. Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like you have a very old version of the driver. You can check the driver's version using: `SQLServerDriver drv = new SQLServerDriver(); System.out.println(drv.getMajorVersion() + "." + drv.getMinorVersion());`

Comment: I got SQLServerDriver version 1.1 using above code given by you.

Comment: That is a totally outdated and obsolete driver you need to get a recent one (at least version 3, better version 4)

Answer (score 6):

Try to update your driver to [Version 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774). Version 3.0 is very old.
Alternatively you can use [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) JDBC Driver. This is a third-party driver but supports much more versions of Microsoft SQLServer.

Comment: He is actually using version 1.1 which is even more outdated that 3.0

Comment: One additional thing to be aware-of.  That link (above) will give you sqljdbc version 6.  My app choked on 6 (probably my JRE was too old).  I had to extract the sqljdbc4.jar and rename it to sqljdbc.jar.  Then everything was fixed!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me after upgrading to Microsoft JDBC Drivers version 4.0