# while testing connection with sql server

Tags: websphere

The test connection operation failed for data source C on server server1 at node PF1RJRMENode06 with the following exception: : The server version is not supported. The target server must be SQL Server 2000 or later. DSRA0010E: SQL State = 08S01, Error Code = 0. View JVM logs for further details.

tried with all jars to connect but not worked.

Answer (score 0):

This question was already answered here: [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The server version is not supported. The target server must be SQL Server 2000 or later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18629266/com-microsoft-sqlserver-jdbc-sqlserverexception-the-server-version-is-not-suppo)
That question was based on using a standlaone java app, not one deployed on WebSphere app server, but the root cause is the same, in this case, WebSphere is reporting the exception directly from the driver.